# ExactTarget, Query for Open and Click Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am trying to write a query to bring all the records for Open and Click event based on Subscriber Key.

So I want to see records like; if someone open email on 1/1/2010 9:10 but no click then click column value should be blank or N/A and if he again open same email at 1/1/2010 10:00 and Click as well then Click Column should be filled with Click event date.

```sql
SELECT  j.jobid ,
        j.SchedTime ,
        J.EMAILNAME AS EMAILNAME ,
        J.EMAILSUBJECT AS EMAILSUBJECT ,
        C.EVENTDATE AS CLICKDATE ,
        O.EVENTDATE AS OPENDATE
FROM    CLICK_BACKUP_PLAN AS C
        INNER JOIN Job_Backup_Plan AS J ON C.JOBID = J.JOBID
        INNER JOIN OPEN_BACKUP_PLAN AS O ON O.JOBID = C.JOBID
WHERE   C.SubscriberKey = 'ABCD@XYZ'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this.  Use the `job_backup_plan` Data Extension as the source and then left join on the activity tables by `jobid`.  I'd use a left join, because the subscriber may not have opened or clicked on an email in the send.

The `group by` and the `max()` functions will return the most recent `eventdate`.

```
select
j.jobid
, j.schedtime
, j.emailname
, j.emailsubject
, max(c.eventdate) as clickdate
, max(o.eventdate) as opendate
from job_backup_plan as j
left join click_backup_plan as c on (c.jobid = j.jobid)
left join open_backup_plan as o on (o.jobid = j.jobid)
where 
(o.subscriberkey = 'abcd@xyz.com' or c.subscriberkey = 'abcd@xyz.com')
group by 
j.jobid
, j.schedtime
, j.emailname
, j.emailsubject
```